# SQL solution to extract total number of hours from a string column

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

I have a varchar(255) column in table1:

```
    time 
--------------------------                
    Monday|10:00-18:00    
    Tuesday|10:00-16:00   
    Friday|10:00-20:00
```

How do I extract the number of hours from the above column using SQLite? I tried using varchar() and datetime() none of which worked. Should I be using regex to get the time?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the time values using:

```
select substr(time, -11, 5), substr(time, -5)
```

You can then use `julianday()` to get the difference in seconds (or any other unit):

```
select round((julianday(substr(time, -5)) - julianday(substr(time, -11, 5))) * 60 * 60 * 24) as seconds_diff
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=fda09551825cf60fd878922b1a053d9e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your help, once again.